# Optimize 2 mysql queries to one

Tags: mysql

User has **pets**, pets may have **pictures** One picture may be set as mainpicture (mainpic=0 or mainpic=1)

I need to get all the pet data from the pets table and I also need the picture id where mainpic=1 or first picture or null if he has no picture in the picture table. I need to get the pet data even if it has no picture at all.

Currently I use 2 queries to get this done:
SELECT * FROM pets WHERE pets.userId='$userId' ORDER BY pets.created ASC LIMIT 5
...
for each result: SELECT id FROM pictures WHERE petId = '$petId' ORDER BY mainpic DESC LIMIT 1

I need this optimized and in one query.

Thanks,
Hamlet

Comment: aside from my answer below, it looks like you're not using prepared statements for your queries (which you probably should be).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use an inner join to omit unmatched records

```
select * 
from pets inner join pictures 
on pets.id = petId and mainpic=1
where userId=? 
order by pets.created ASC limit 5
```

if you only want null in the picture related fields but want the pet info (your Q was a little unclear) then use a left join

```
select * 
from pets left join pictures 
on pets.id = petId and mainpic=1
where userId=? 
order by pets.created ASC limit 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM pets
INNER JOIN pictures ON pictures.petid = pets.id AND pictures.mainpic = 1
WHERE pets.userid='$userid'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM pets p
     LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT *
        FROM pictures pict
        WHERE pict.mainpic = 1
     ) pict ON pict.petid = p.petid
WHERE p.userid = '$userid'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  (
        SELECT  id
        FROM    pictures pi
        WHERE   pi.petid = pe.petid
        ORDER BY
                mainpic DESC
        LIMIT 1
        )
FROM    pets pe
```